# TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/profile/

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

I am trying to make a profile page, which simply is a page with user details, such as firstname, lastname, email, etc. But I think there is something wrong with my view or my url.py or my setting, which gives me an error of TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/profile/ (users/profile.html). Other pages are working fine though.

Here is my traceback:

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 34, in inner response = get_response(request)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in _get_response response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 113, in _get_response response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/users/views.py", line 32, in profile return render(request, 'users/profile.html', args)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts.py", line 19, in render content = loader.render_to_string(template_name, context, request, using=using)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site packages/django/template/loader.py", line 61, in render_to_string template = get_template(template_name, using=using)*

*File "/Documents/morse_log/m_env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/template/loader.py", line 19, in get_template raise TemplateDoesNotExist(template_name, chain=chain)*

*Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist at /users/profile/*
*Exception Value: users/profile.html*

settings.py:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # My apps
    'morse_logs',
    'users',

    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

/users/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path, include
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from . import views


app_name = 'users'

urlpatterns = [
    # Include default auth urls.
    path('', include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),

    # Registration
    path(r'/register/', views.register, name='register'),
    path(r'/profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),

]
```

/users/profile.html:

```
{% block content %}
<title>Profile</title>
<div class="container">
    <p>
        {{user}}
        {{user.first_name}}
    </p>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

users/views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.contrib.auth import login
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm
from users.forms import RegistrationForm
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your views here.
def register(request):
    """Register a new user"""
    if request.method != 'POST':
        # Display blank registration form
        form = RegistrationForm()
    else:
        # Process completed form
        form = RegistrationForm(data=request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            new_user = form.save()
            # Log the user in and then redirect to home page
            login(request, new_user)
            return redirect('morse_logs:index')

    # Display a blank or invalid form.
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'registration/register.html', context)


def profile(request):
    args = {'user': request.user}
    return render(request, 'users/profile.html', args)
```

users/model.py:
**(in my text editor, it says 'sender' value is not used,
Unresolved attributes reference 'objects' for class UserProfile)**

```
from django.db import models
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

# Create your models here.


class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=100, default='')


def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = UserProfile.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

    post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=User)
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm


class RegistrationForm(UserCreationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'username',
            'first_name',
            'last_name',
            'email',
            'password1',
            'password2'
        )

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(RegistrationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']

        if commit:
            user.save()

        return user
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to add the template directory in the templates list:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

So replace the following TEMPLATES list.

```
TEMPLATES = [
        {
            'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
            'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
            'APP_DIRS': True,
            'OPTIONS': {
                'context_processors': [
                    'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                    'django.template.context_processors.request',
                    'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
                ],
            },
        },
    ]
```

And create template in the following format:

```
      users  
        ----|templates
               ----|users
                  -----|profile.html
```